# android firestore document vs. subcollection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am confused by android firstore document and subcollection.

This example will generate below data structure:

```
root-> a -> b -> c -> d -> field1:apple
                           field2:orange
```

The code as below:

```
private void addItem() {
    FirebaseFirestore rootRefs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("field1", "apple");
    item.put("field2", "orange");
    rootRefs.collection("a")
            .document("b")
            .collection("c")
            .document("d")
            .set(item)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                }
            });
}
```

The subcollection and document node appear alternatively: a,c vs. b,d.

But how to implement similar data structure without d node (as below):

```
root-> a -> b -> d -> field1:apple
                      field2:orange
```

Since the .add method only available for document but not collection, we can not just remove the d (document) since c (collection) do not has the add method.

How should I modify my code?

Comment: You can't have a document that's not inside a collection or subcollection.  Documents can't immediately contain other documents.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I wish to implement that. so I have to add a extra collection to include my last document! Is that a waste just like add one more layer in the tree? Or is it possible to connect collection to collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the .add method only available for document but not collection, we can not just remove the d (document) since c (collection) do not has the add method.

There is no way you can achieve this. A document should exist beneath a collection or a subcollection. A document **cannot** exist beneath another document.

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model), the only structure that is permited is as follows:

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')
```

There is no way in Firestore to store a collection beneath other collection. So the following line of code is not allowed:

```
db.collection('coll').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc') //Not allowed
```

As there is no way to store a document beneath other document.

```
db.collection('coll').doc('doc').doc('subdoc') //Not allowed
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have to add one more collection!